# How to bring selected list item position in centre of listview in android

Tags: android

How to bring selected list item position in centre of lisview in android 
I need to use this method 
public void smoothScrollByOffset (int offset)

How to find offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you actually want is:
[`smoothScrollToPositionFromTop (int position, int offset)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(int,%20int))
This will scroll the list item you indicate with `position` so that it is `offset` pixels below the top edge of the `ListView`.

To make it scroll to the center you could do something like:

```
int listViewHeight = myListView.getMeasuredHeight();
myListView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(myItemPosition, (listViewHeight / 2));
```

This will put the top edge of your chosen item half way down the `ListView`.

If you wanted to go further, you could also get the measured height of the item's view and subtract half of that from the offset too. This would truly "*center*" the item at the mid height of the `ListView`.